# port forward from wan to lan

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, webmin

How to create rule to forward all incoming 80 -port traffic from public IP address to another server in the LAN via Ubuntu linux firewall (using webmin).
Server have two IP addresses public and internal.

Comment: Did you read http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/LinuxFirewall#Setting_up_port_forwarding?

Comment: now I have read it, thanks. but where i can see log file because looks like that my setop not working...

Comment: -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination IP_address_LAN_web_server; adding this line forward do not working...